# Passing environment variables from one module to another in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-library

I am working on project that has Two Apps(App A, App B). There are around 100 components used by both apps. So I have created an Angular Library and organised those components in Modules. Everything works fine. I am stuck when i need to pass environment to the modules in the library.

```
@NgModule({
 imports:[
 LibModule2, // need to pass environment from LibModule1
 LibModule3,
]
})
export class LibModule1{
  export function forRoot(environment):ModuleWithProviders{
   return {
       ngModule:LibModule1,
       providers:[
        {provider:ENV, useValue:environment}
       ]
   }
 }
}


//App1

@NgModule({
  imports:[
   LibModule1.forRoot(environment)
  ]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

I only need LibModule1 in the Apps. But need to pass environment to LibModule2, LibModule3 as well. how can I do this? Am i approaching it in a wrong way?

Comment: May be try using a class for injecting provider value. And have appropriate getters in class. 
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#the-provider-object-literal

Comment: Still stuck. can you provide a code sample addressing a similar scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I have such a problem for a while and best solution i found is this:

Add a static Class to Your Library Modules:

```
export class Lib1Module {
  static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: Lib1Module,
      providers: [{provide: 'config', useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}

export class Lib2Module {
  static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: Lib2Module,
      providers: [{provide: 'config', useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}
```

Then pass `environment` from `app.module` to your `Lib1Module` & `Lib2Module` Like this:

```
imports:[
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    GigLib1Module.forRoot(environment),
    GigLib2Module.forRoot(environment)
]
```

Now, `environment` file injected into your library.

How to use it:

```
environment :any
constructor(@Inject('config') config) 
{         
     if (config) {
     this.environment = config;
   } 
}
```

Now Environment can be changed from Main Project easily.

Comment: I already have that working. My problem is, I don't want import all the library modules in the main project. Instead import one parent module, pass the env to the parent module and the parent must pass the env to it's child modules. That's my actual need.

Comment: Use a service to provide Environment for Your, Then Inject it wherever you want, i think this might solve your problem, Modules are just namespaces and limit functionalities may cause a problem in that case